# Multiple Variables Passing URL

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I need some help with this!
I´m passing multiple variables through URL and on the landing page I have this in my code:

```
str = "
    SELECT
    *
    FROM wp_usermail
    WHERE ID= ".@$_GET['ID']"& Till=".@$_GET['Till'];
```

I want to be more accurate to select the right information from the database so both ID and Till needs to be correct otherwise you cant see the content on the page.

Right now I get parse error: `syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ rides again.

Comment: @Quentin +1 for Bobby Tables! :)

Comment: First of all you'll have to set the id to INT and don't forget to use mysql_real_escape_string() to avoid SQL injections !

if(isset($_GET['ID'])){
$id = (int) $_GET['ID'];
}

Comment: Be careful with this code - it's a possible setup for a SQL injection. Make sure you validate user inputs (`$_GET[]` values) before entering them into the query. i.e. PHP validation, and especially `mysqli_real_escape_string();`

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, use parameterised queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace it with this:

```
$str = "
SELECT
*
FROM wp_usermail 
WHERE ID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET ['ID']) . "' AND Till = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET ['Till']) . "'";
```

You were missing the `$` in the variables' name, multiple `.`s, correct quotes around your variables and you didn't escape the input, which you should always do for security.

One more thing: you should stop using the `mysql_*` functions and start using either *mysqli* or *PDO*, since `mysql_*` are now deprecated.

Comment: Alright, I´m still a kind of a noob in this but I will have it in mind! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the `$` in variable name.